# Buttons in a GridView

Tags: android, android-button, android-gridview, onitemclick

I decided to use a custom GridView for my app, I have used a TextView for each single view in the GridView and everything worked just as it should , but then due to design purposes I decided to change the TextViews to Buttons.
Now the problem is the grid's onItemClick  doesn't work anymore, any ideas on how to use Buttons in a GridView? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: can u post code xml and java?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a custom adapter, and put your button in that.

You CAN just use the onClick event of the TextView (so, you don't actually need to use a button if you are just trying to capture onClick envent).

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I do want to use a Button because it looks way better for me. The problem is I don't know where to place that Button's onClickListener , should it be the Gridview's onItemClickListener? or should it have another ClickListener?